# Fibonacci C++ return Error

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I wanted to create a function which prints out the fib numbers. But i can´t fix this error. Next allways stays the same from the initialisation. I´m a very beginner of Cpp.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

int fib(int &n)
{
    int first = 0, second = 1, next{};

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i <= 1) {
            int next = i;

        }

        else
        {
            int next = first + second;
            first = second;
            second = next;

        }
        std::cout << next << std::endl;
    }
return next;
}



int main()

{

    int stelle;

    std::cout << "Bitte geben Sie die Stelle der Fibonacci Folge ein die Sie erhalten möchten" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> stelle;
    fib(stelle);

    std::cout << "Tastedrücken zum Beenden";
    int var;
    std::cin >> var;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: can you provide the error?

Comment: Your `i` always starts at `0`, which means it's *always* `<= 1` which means it *always* enters your very first `if` which contains `return next`. Your `for` loop always hits `return next` on its first iteration, it's impossible for it to ever go further than that regardless of the inputs to your function.

Comment: How do you know what it returns?  You don't capture the return value.

Comment: Don't put `return` in the `for` loop if you want it to continue with the following iterations.

Comment: If your `for` loop completes, it doesn't return a value.  Also, because you have a `return` in both the `if` and `else`, only one iteration will occur before returning.

Comment: By making the parameter a reference, you've disallowed someone from calling `fib(5)`.

Comment: The first code was a wrong version

Comment: If i cin 3.. i get 4 zeros. Because my return next always stays zero

Comment: Research variable scope. You have more than 1 next variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes me think that there is lack of clarity in how to translate the math to code.

You can implement it using an iterative logic or recursive logic.

In either case, there are two running numbers that you have to deal with.

Let's say you start with the 0 and 1 as the starting numbers.
In the next iteration, they need to be 1 and 1.
In the next iteration, they need to be 1 and 2.
In the next iteration, they need to be 2 and 3.
In the next iteration, they need to be 3 and 5.

etc.

At the end of the iteration (or recursion), the second number from that pair is the final Fibonacci number.

Here's one such implementation.

```
int fib(int n)
{
   if ( n == 0 )
   {
      return 0;
   }

   int ans1 = 0;
   int ans2 = 1;
   for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i )
   {
      int temp = ans2;
      ans2 = ans1 + ans2;
      ans1 = temp;
   }
   return ans2;
}
```

A working program:

```
#include <iostream>

int fib(int n)
{
   if ( n == 0 )
   {
      return 0;
   }

   int ans1 = 0;
   int ans2 = 1;
   for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i )
   {
      int temp = ans2;
      ans2 = ans1 + ans2;
      ans1 = temp;
   }
   return ans2;
}

int main()
{
   int stelle;

   std::cout << "Bitte geben Sie die Stelle der Fibonacci Folge ein die Sie erhalten möchten" << std::endl;
   std::cin >> stelle;
   for ( int i = 1; i < stelle; ++i )
   {
      std::cout << "fib(" << i << "): " << fib(i) << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The output of the program when the input is 20:

```
Bitte geben Sie die Stelle der Fibonacci Folge ein die Sie erhalten m▒chten
fib(1): 1
fib(2): 1
fib(3): 2
fib(4): 3
fib(5): 5
fib(6): 8
fib(7): 13
fib(8): 21
fib(9): 34
fib(10): 55
fib(11): 89
fib(12): 144
fib(13): 233
fib(14): 377
fib(15): 610
fib(16): 987
fib(17): 1597
fib(18): 2584
fib(19): 4181
```

Comment: thanks! Now i have to understand it. Why does it work that way.

Comment: why do you return ans2 if i return ans1 i get the same result. But if i retrurn temp

Comment: and why do i have to use two for-loops

Comment: It's not possible that you get same answer whether you return `ans1` or `ans2`. They are different numbers except when `n` is equal to 2.

Comment: The `for` loop in `main` is there just so you can see the entire sequence of numbers, not just the final number. It gives more credibility to the final answer.